# How to stop Eslint from giving me a "Compiled with errors" screen every time there is a single Eslint error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I created my project with `npx create-react-app my-app` and setup Eslint to use Airbnb preset but every single Eslint problem like an unused variable gives me a "Compiled with errors" screen which I have to close before I can see the changes on my website and I was wondering how can I prevent Eslint from showing that screen while still seeing the errors in my code?

My `.eslint.js` file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    env: {
        browser: true,
        es2021: true,
    },
    extends: ['plugin:react/recommended', 'airbnb'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
        ecmaFeatures: {
            jsx: true,
        },
        ecmaVersion: 'latest',
        sourceType: 'module',
    },
    plugins: ['react', '@typescript-eslint'],
    rules: {
        'max-len': ['error', { code: 120 }],
        indent: ['error', 4],
        'react/jsx-indent': ['error', 4],
        'react/jsx-indent-props': ['error', 4],
        'linebreak-style': 0,
        'react/jsx-filename-extension': [2, { extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'] }],
        'react/function-component-definition': [
            2,
            {
                namedComponents: 'arrow-function',
                unnamedComponents: 'arrow-function',
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: @jabaa I want it to be linted and see the errors in my IDE so I can fix them, but as it is right now, developing is cumbersome as I get this error screen every time I create a variable that I haven't yet used because I haven't gotten to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the default behavior of react-scripts. You can suppress that behavior by defining environment variable `ESLINT_NO_DEV_ERRORS=true`.

Full list of available environment variables for react-scripts.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration